# Android Studio/flutter: Deploy a JSON file into android bundle storage without using assets folder

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio

At build time, I'd love to deploy a JSON file into my app's internal storage at

`/data/data/<bundleid>/files`

This way my underlying C++ code can access files there.

With flutter on Android Studio, I can't seem to use the `assets` feature in yaml to deploy files to that location. That feature seems to require native code Kotlin/Swift to access the bundled data.

What should I do?